# Discrete Fourier Transform and Incomplete Fourier Series

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, audio, frequency-spectrum, dft

I'm working on a paper where I'm collecting sound pressure data from a chord's wave and trying to create a frequency spectrum to find the individual frequencies that make up the chord.

However, I can't process too many data points (software). To ensure a sampling rate higher than twice the highest note, I can't collect SPL data for the entire period of the chord's wave.

Would the DFT still work and pick up the individual frequencies on the frequency spectrum if not the entire chord's period is collected?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the sampling rate then?

Comment: "too many data points": Um, why? You're doing something strange; with the most prolific DFT library, a [16 year old server CPU does about 100 transforms of length 65536 per second](http://www.fftw.org/speed/CoreDuo-3.0GHz-icc64/), so I'm a bit confused how this becomes a practical limit anywhere with audio sampling rates; a six year old desktop CPU does about [300 DFTs of that length](http://www.fftw.org/speed/Ryzen-7-3.6GHz/) per second. All this single-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I can't process too many data points (software).

Why not? That would be unusual limit. By today's standard that requires very little memory and CPU.

> To ensure a sampling rate higher than twice the highest note,

Careful here. A note typically consists of a harmonic line spectrum and NOT a single frequency.  You need capture enough harmonics to get the pitch from the harmonic spacing. The fundamental can be weak or missing entirely.

> Would the DFT still work and pick up the individual frequencies on the frequency spectrum if not the entire chord's period is collected?

Unlikely. The FFT isn't a great tool for pitch detection in the first place. It's frequency resolution is given by $\Delta f = f_s/N$ where $f_s$ is the sample rate and $N$ the FFT length. Short FFTs have very poor resolution.